# show UItableview scrollbar for few seconds on page load

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, xcode4

I am having number of rows in UITableView. To let people know that there are many items I want to display tableview scrollbar for few secs when view appears. Is there any method or delegate which i missed?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
[self.tableView flashScrollIndicators];
```

However, you can't make them visible unless user is scrolling the `UITableView`.

Answer (score 0):

Because UITableView is a kind of UIScrollView, you can call `flashScrollIndicators`